Angular SSG Prerendering gives timeout when rendering big numb of urls (V17+)
I have angular v19 app and I'm using SSG with following angular.json settings
{
    ...
     "prerender":{
                 
        "routesFile": "prerender-urls.txt",
        "discoverRoutes": false
     },
       "ssr": false
    ...
}

When I render a few routes it works, but when I try to render a big number of routes like 10K, the backend api is returning response slower.
Because of that angular build pipeline is throwing an error timeout error like this
 Request for: http://ng-localhost/artists was aborted.
TimeoutError: The operation was aborted due to timeout
    at t.signal.addEventListener.once (.angular/prerender-root/0e49d623-08ac-4921-af23-47b186294be5/chunk-4RSAFBPM.mjs:106:5215)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:825:20)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:760:26)
    at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:370:10)
    at AbortController.abort (node:internal/abort_controller:392:5)
    at EventTarget.abort (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5038:21)
    at [nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:825:20)
    at EventTarget.dispatchEvent (node:internal/event_target:760:26)
    at abortSignal (node:internal/abort_controller:370:10)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (node:internal/abort_controller:127:7)


X [ERROR] An error occurred while prerendering route '/artists'.

Error: Terminating worker thread
    at Object.ThreadTermination (...piscina\dist\errors.js:5:30)
    at WorkerInfo.destroy (...piscina\dist\worker_pool\index.js:107:43)
    at ThreadPool._removeWorker (...piscina\dist\index.js:250:20)
    at ThreadPool.destroy (...piscina\dist\index.js:434:18)
    at WorkerPool.destroy (...piscina\dist\index.js:631:65)
    at ...@angular\build\src\utils\server-rendering\prerender.js:147:35
    at async Promise.all (index 151)
    at async renderPages (...@angular\build\src\utils\server-rendering\prerender.js:151:9)
    at async prerenderPages (...@angular\build\src\utils\server-rendering\prerender.js:93:49)
    at async executePostBundleSteps (...@angular\build\src\builders\application\execute-post-bundle.js:68:73)

I researched and tried many workaround with no luck in finding a proper solution to increase this timeout issue.
Is there any way to hijack Angular's build pipeline or other way to increase this timeout.
this is a very common case I believe but yet I couldn't find any resource online

Update: I opened up a git issue but its closed and not planned.

i have same problem when upgrade to v19.
I realized that the problem was because I was making my API calls like this.
http.get("api/apiadress")
I'm using a middleware (http-proxy-middleware) in the server.ts file and prerender was working without any problems in v18.
When I updated to v19 I now noticed that API calls start with address "ng-localhost".
The problem was solved when starts with http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1 to API calls.

I dont have proper solution yet but I think one of these can help other
Solution 1 : Increase timeout from 30sec to 100sec or more in this file,

from AbortSignal.timeout(30_000) to AbortSignal.timeout(100_000) or
any  desired value

I found it from this git issue which is related to my issue.
this approach is not clean as you have to do workaround for CICD and need to maintain it in version control across entire team.
Solution 2 : If Api is a bottleneck then reducing parallel build worker size to 1 or less will help
you can configure the NG_BUILD_MAX_WORKERS environment variable. Which defaults to a max of 4 (reference)
in js file
process.env.NG_BUILD_MAX_WORKERS = 1 

or for cli
set NG_BUILD_MAX_WORKERS = 1 

